# Testing Primality in C++

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me out? I am trying to test primality but I cant seem to get this to work. For whatever reason, whenever I run it, it runs fine as long as I start with a number that is not prime. However, after running something that is not prime, the output is "0 1" instead of just 0. It also seems that if I start with a number that is not prime, everything is "0 1" instead of the correct output.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int num;
    int x = 2;
    //cin >> num;
    while(cin >> num)         //(x<=num-1) 
    { 

        for(x<=num-1; x++;)
        {
            if(num%x==0)
            { 
                cout << "0" << endl ; //1 is prime, 0 is not prime
                break; 
            }

            if(x==num)
            {
                cout << "1" << endl ;
                break; 
            }
        }

        if(x==num)
        {
            cout << "1" << endl ;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did the debugger say?

Comment: `for(x<=num-1; x++;)` semicolons in the wrong place. Try `for(;x<=num-1; x++)`

Comment: If you combine the last comment with the one answer, then you get the solution. remove the second cout and fix your for loop syntax.

Answer (score 1):

well you have the cout << "1" twice, you probably didn't mean that

Answer (score 0):

```
for(x<=num-1; x++;)
```

the semicolons are in wrong places, so instead of stating a condition `x<=num-1` under which execution should happen you state the `x<=num-1` expression is just evaluated with no effect and then in case of a prime number `x` is incremented until

```
if(num%x==0)
```

is true because in fact `num==x` at this point. Then you print your '0' and next you print '1' because

```
if(x==num)
{
  cout << "1" << endl ;
}
```

is true.